# Image and Text Slider Responsive problem in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a website on React js. I have no clue how I can implement the responsive image slider with text.

I tried to do it like the browser. But for responsive I think the image and the text should be aligned vertically!

```
  class Projects extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
       super();
                    }

    render() {
    return (
     <StyledContainer>
       <div className="container">
           <div className="projectSlideDiv">
           <h2 className="headerProjectSlide">OUR SUCCESSFUL 
          PROJECTS</h2>
           <h3 className="titleIntroProjectSlide">
          WE CRAFT YOUR PROJECT WITH CARE
        </h3>
        <div className="paraProjectSlide">
          Our main focus is to make the User Experience very simple and
          easy.
        </div>
        <p className="paraProjectSlide">Simplicity is our Strength.</p>
       </div>

      <Carousel showArrows={false} showThumbs={false} showStatus={false}>
        <div>
          <div className="projectSlide">
            <div className="firstHalfSlide">
              <img src={sliderImage} />
            </div>

            <div className="secondHalfSlide">
              <h3 className="titleProjects">E-COMMERCE WEBSITE</h3>
              <h2 className="projectName">Nextgen E-Commerce</h2>
              <p className="paraProjectText">
                Nextgen UI is all about a smart solution for clothing
                business. It's a great solution for a e- commerce 
                 business.
                It care about our customer and satisfy their need with 
                easy
                solutions.Nextgen UI is all about a smart solution for
                clothing business. It's a great solution for a e-commerce
                business. It care about our customer and satisfy their 
                need
                with easy solutions.
              </p>

              <div className="readmoreBtnPosition">
                <div class="readmoreBtn">Read More</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>                  
        </div>

           <div>
            <img src="" />
          </div>
        </Carousel>
       </div>
     </StyledContainer>
     );
    }
   }
```

[image]

[image]
I have given the responsive portion I created

CSS:
This is the css I tried. Can anyone suggest anything? What media query should I write to fix this?

```
@media ${screenSize.size650} {
   .projectSlideDiv {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

   .headerProjectSlide {
     padding: 4px 4px;
     font-size: 0.7em;
     text-align: center;
   }

   .titleIntroProjectSlide {
     padding: 9px 1px;
     font-size: 0.8em;
     margin: 1px 8px;
     text-align: center;
   }

  .paraProjectSlide {
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    margin: 1px 2px;
  }

  .firstHalfSlide {
    margin: 1px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use react-bootstrap package for create Responsive web aplication.
Go through this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap

Comment: is it possible without bootstrap?

Comment: Yes possible set width according to screen by using CSS, but bootstrap was best option :)